# Is it "slough" or "slew"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Which is the proper word to use to indicate a large amount of something - "slough" or "slew"?  Eg:

*StackExchange now has a slough of potential new sites in Area51.*

*English.stackexchange.com has a slew of questions about pronunciation.*

Google indicates "a slew of" is more popular than "a slough of", but isn't *slew* the past tense of *slay*?  It seems that slough, as in a slow moving channel of water, would be a better metaphor.  No?

Comment: Good question, and a mimesis of my own mental ramblings about the word. I'm glad Martha so succinctly got a handle on this one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The phrase is definitely "a slew of". This meaning of the word *[slew](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slew)* comes from Irish *slue* "crowd" and has nothing to do with the verb *to slay*; the fact that the two words are spelled identically is just another accident of language evolution.

Comment: Thanks, Martha. I had always wondered about that, but somehow never got up the energy to track it down.

Comment: I think you are right, but do you have a citation?

Comment: @augurar: check the link.

Comment: @Marthaª The Wiktionary article didn't cite their sources.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slew "perhaps from Irish slua army, host, throng, from Old Irish slúag; akin to Lithuanian slaugyti to tend"

Answer (score 12):

**Fact**
Indeed, [*slew*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slew) is the past tense of [*slay*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slay). However, [*slew*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slew) is also a verb in its own right that means *turn*!

In [American informal usage*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/slew_3), the noun [*slew*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slew), as you rightly indicated, indicates a large number. As in your second example, *slew of questions* is not an uncommon phrase. Thus, the usage of *slough* in a similar vein would be incorrect. That *slough* and *slew* could both be pronounced in the same way is a possible reason for the confusion of the two in writing.

The noun [*slough*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slough) primarily means *swamp* or *bog*, and it often has a dreary or negative connotation, e.g. *Slough of Despond* (John Bunyan's *The Pilgrim's Progess*), *slough of moral filth*, etc. It can also be spelled [*slew*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slew)!

---

**Opinion**
Frankly, I do not at all think *slough* would be a better metaphor, as you suggest. Furthermore, I do not think the etymology of the [*US informal*] noun *slew* has any relation to that of the verb *slay* or its past tense.*

---

**Addendum***
Interestingly, Merriam-Webster suggests the origin of the noun *slew* thus:

> perhaps from Irish *slua* army, host, throng, from Old Irish *slúag*;

---

**According to the [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/slew_3)*

Comment: Certainly a swamp wouldn't be a better metaphor than slew since it apparently does mean a large quantity of something and wouldn't actually be a metaphor at all. However, in the pacific northwest, we know a slough as a slow moving channel of water that was at one time used to transport logs. I was imagining a large amount of something floating down the slough, like "a sloughful of kids". That would be a better metaphor than the past tense of slay.

Comment: @gilly3: Yes, indeed, *slough* also means *slow-moving channel*. I see your point. I was being lazy in not considering all the definitions of *slough* and simply settled for its most popular meaning! But, as Martha also pointed out, *slew* (n.) comes from the Old Irish..

Comment: "Slew of" meaning "many" is also in my (UK) usage.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Interesting, especially since it was the Cambridge Dictionary (British) I consulted that indicated that this usage of *slew* was distinctively American (either in usage or origin, not specified)!